# How to select one row each conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trouble with my code. I want to get only one rows each conditions in MySQL.

I have a table like that:

```
ID - Position  - Content
1       2         abc
2       1         def
3       1         ghk
4       3         pol
5       2         lop
6       4         gty
```

So I want the result returned like: position = 1 -> highest id row then pass to position = 2 -> highest id row. I have no idea to code it.

Comment: Which result do you want?  For example, for `position = 1`, do you want `2 - 1 - def` or `3 - 1 - ghk`?  What are the rules that determine which result is the one to return?

Comment: Can you add the code that you are having trouble with - Also, can you add an example of how the output should appear. The sentence "I want to get only one rows each conditions in mysql" is unclear, can you reword it?

Comment: I want the result returned like: position = 1 -> first row have position = 1 then pass to position = 2 -> first row have position = 2... I have no idea to code :(

Comment: Rows are not ordered in a relational database. Instead of saying you want the 'first row' with `position = 2`, you should say that you want the row with `position = 2` and the lowest `ID`. In SQL: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Position = 2 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub query to test the id

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(ID int, Position int, Content varchar(3));
insert into t values
(1   ,    2    ,     'abc'),
(2   ,    1    ,     'def'),
(3   ,    1    ,     'ghk'),
(4   ,    3    ,     'pol'),
(5   ,    2    ,     'lop'),
(6   ,    4    ,     'gty');


select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(id) from t t1 where t1.position = t.position);

+------+----------+---------+
| ID   | Position | Content |
+------+----------+---------+
|    1 |        2 | abc     |
|    2 |        1 | def     |
|    4 |        3 | pol     |
|    6 |        4 | gty     |
+------+----------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below query

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT min(id) FROM t GROUP BY position);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query..

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table-name ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

DISTINCT operates on a single column. DISTINCT for multiple columns is not supported.
same column cant not print 
And 
order by id asc use and all record print 1 - n means minimum id

Comment: 'DISTINCT operates on a single column' this is incorrect distinct operates on all columns selected.